# Kotlin object private when accessed from Java

Tags: java, kotlin

I have some Kotlin code like this

```
object NativeInterface {
    // Used to load the 'native-lib' library on application startup.
    public val effectDescriptionMap: Map<String, EffectDescription>
```

and I'm trying to access from Java like this:

```
Effect it = NativeInterface.effectDescriptionMap[menuItem.title];
```

But it keeps saying that `effectDescriptionMap` is private, even though I explicitly placed `public` on it. From Kotlin I can access but not from Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NativeInterface is an object not a class. You have to access the INSTANCE

```
NativeInterface.INSTANCE.getEffectDescriptionMap()
```

Comment: While this is indeed the solution for his example, the real reason for getting the reported error is, that he tried to directly access the backing field of the property. In java, properties are usually behind getter and setter methods. Kotlin will generate these under the hood, so a property like `val effectDescriptionMap` has a `getEffectDescriptionMap()` method in java to read and a `setEffectDescriptionMap(...)` to change the private backing field `effectDescriptionMap`.